# Как после заполнения форм ее скрыть

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте! Есть поле для ввода числа. Под полем для ввода кнопка "Отправить". Как сделать так, чтобы после отправки данной формы, она скрылась? 
Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но в JS вообще не сильна.

Comment: Добавьте код...

Comment: просто html-страница с формой для ввода числа.

Comment: она ниоткуда не появляется. она там всегда есть. мне надо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку отправить, она исчезла.

Comment: я думала сделать событие onClick при нажатии на кнопку отправить. И написать функцию для этого события, что при нажатии делать поле hidden, но не уверена, что это правильно.

Comment: Нет, не одноразовая. Она должна просто скрыться. Задача этой формы такова: пользователь вводит туда число. Потом это форма скрывается и начинает производится анимация с использованием этого числа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принцип должен быть понятен, остальное (анимации, появление вновь и прочее) уже сможете сами додумать.

```js
function hide(form) {
      form.classList.add('hidden')
   }
```

```css
form.hidden {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="text">
  <input type="button" onclick="hide(this.form)" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(форма).on('submit',function(){
    $(форма).hide();
});
```

При отправке формы - форму скрыть.

Answer (score 1):

```js
send.addEventListener("click", (e)=>e.target.parentNode.style.display = "none");
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="button" value="send" id="send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form onsubmit="this.style.display = 'none'; return false">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```